# React-Final-Form not reruning the validation when checkbox is unchecked

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, react-final-form

I'm using react-final-form with fonk.
My problem is that the user can submit the form without the checkbox being checked - this happens when you check is and then uncheck it. I don't know why but then it doesn't show any errors and it gives a green light to submit the form.

```
        return (
        <MessageFormSection>
            <h2>Wypełnij formularz</h2>
            <small>Odpowiadamy naprawdę szybko!</small>

            <Form 
                onSubmit={() => {
                    emailjs.sendForm('service_xuu4z8k', 'template_54zt0z9', '#contact-form', 'user_C1OXTe9qBeqb5ZOmCejLc')
                        .then((result) => {
                            setUserInfo('Twoja wiadomośc została wysłana poprawnie');
                            disableSubmit();
                        }, (error) => {
                            setUserInfo('Podczas wysyłania twojej wiadomości pojawił się błąd - Wiadomość nie została wysłana.');
                        });
                }}
                initialValues={{
                    fullName: '',
                    email: '',
                    title: '',
                    message: '',
                    policy: null,
                }}
                validate={(values) => formValidation.validateForm(values)}
                render={({handleSubmit}) => (
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} id="contact-form">
                        <Field name="fullName">
                            {({input, meta}) => (
                                <div className="fullname-box">
                                    <label htmlFor="form-fullname-input">Imię i Nazwisko</label>
                                    <input {...input} id="form-fullname-input" placeholder="Jan Kowalski"/>
                                    {meta.error && meta.touched && <span>{meta.error}</span>}
                                </div>
                            )}
                        </Field>
                        <Field name="email" type="email">
                            {({input, meta}) => (
                                <div className="email-box">
                                    <label htmlFor="form-phone-input">Email</label>
                                    <input {...input} id="form-phone-input" placeholder="jankowalski@email.com"/>
                                    {meta.error && meta.touched && <span>{meta.error}</span>}
                                </div>
                            )}
                        </Field>
                        <Field name="title">
                            {({input, meta}) => (
                                <div className="title-box">
                                    <label htmlFor="form-title-input">Tytuł</label>
                                    <input {...input} id="form-title-input" placeholder="Wspólna praca nad nowym projektem!?"/>
                                    {meta.error && meta.touched && <span>{meta.error}</span>}
                                </div>
                            )}
                        </Field>
                        <Field name="message">
                            {({input, meta}) => (
                                <div className="message-box">
                                    <label htmlFor="form-message-input">Twoja wiadomość</label>
                                    <textarea rows="3" {...input} id="form-message-input" placeholder="Chciałbym z wami współpracować!"/>
                                    {meta.error && meta.touched && <span>{meta.error}</span>}
                                </div>
                            )}
                        </Field>
                        <Field name="policy" type="checkbox">
                            {({input, meta}) => (
                                <div className="checkbox-box">
                                    <input {...input} id="form-policy-checkbox"/>
                                    <label htmlFor="form-policy-checkbox">Wyrażam zgodę na przetwarzanie moich danych osobowych</label>
                                    {meta.error && meta.touched && <span>{meta.error}</span>}
                                </div>
                            )}
                        </Field>
                        <div className="buttons">
                            <button type="submit" id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                        <span className="user-info">{userInfo}</span>
                    </form>
                )}
            />
        </MessageFormSection>
    )
```

And my FormValidation is this

```
    const validationSchema = {
    field: {
        fullName: [ 
            {
                validator: Validators.required.validator,
                message: "Pełne imię i nazwisko jest wymagane."
            }
        ],
        email: [
            {
                validator: Validators.required.validator,
                message: "Email jest wymagany."
            },
            {
                validator: Validators.email.validator,
                message: "Podaj poprawny adres email."
            }
        ],
        title: [
            {
                validator: Validators.required.validator,
                message: "Podaj tytuł swojej wiadomości."
            }
        ],
        message: [
            {
                validator: Validators.required.validator,
                message: "Podaj wiadomość jaką chcesz do nas wysłać."
            }
        ],
        policy: [
            {
                validator: Validators.required.validator,
                message: "Zgoda jest wymagana do wysłania wiadomości."
            }
        ],        
    },
};
```

with these imports

```
import { createFinalFormValidation } from `@lemoncode/fonk-final-form`
import { Validators } from '@lemoncode/fonk';
```

Comment: please post the code here instead of a link. also post the code to your validation function formValidation.validateForm(values). The problem lies here.

Comment: My guess is that createFinalFormValidation only checks for undefined. when you check and then uncheck, the value is set as false. since false is not equal to  undefined you allowed to go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a custom validator for the checkobx for the reasons mentioned in the comment above.

```
export const checkboxValidator = ({ values }) => {
  const succeeded = values.policy;

  return {
    succeeded,
    message: succeeded
      ? ''
      : 'Required',
    type: 'POLICY',
  };
};
```

import this in FormValidation.js

change your validation schema. remove policy from fields property and instead add it to the records property.

```
  const validationSchema = {
    field: {
        fullName: [ 
            {
                validator: Validators.required.validator,
                message: "Pełne imię i nazwisko jest wymagane."
            }
        ],
        email: [
            {
                validator: Validators.required.validator,
                message: "Email jest wymagany."
            },
            {
                validator: Validators.email.validator,
                message: "Podaj poprawny adres email."
            }
        ],
        title: [
            {
                validator: Validators.required.validator,
                message: "Podaj tytuł swojej wiadomości."
            }
        ],
        message: [
            {
                validator: Validators.required.validator,
                message: "Podaj wiadomość jaką chcesz do nas wysłać."
            }
        ],      
    },
   record: {
      policy: [checkboxValidator]
   },
};
```

Comment: it is already done. you have marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use *fonk-is-true-validator* validator. (https://github.com/Lemoncode/fonk-is-true-validator)

Install

```
yarn add fonk-is-true-validator
```

OR

```
npm install fonk-is-true-validator --save
```

Then, import

```
import { isTrue } from '@lemoncode/fonk-is-true-validator';
```

And, add to Schema

```
field: {
    policy: [Validators.required.validator, isTrue.validator],
    //....other fields
}
```